# Can't resize <div> container with the use of transitions

Tags: javascript, html, css, frontend

I am building a page in HTML/CSS at the moment and ran into a problem with the transition animations. Some context. First here is the HTML code:

This is the HTML code:

```
<body>
    <div class="container">  
        <form id="contact" action="" method="post">
            <i id="icon" style="display: block" class="fas fa-check-circle"></i>
            <h3 class="success-msg">Your <a class="script-link" onclick="myFunction()">script</a> has been approved! <i id="icon2" style="display: none" class="fas fa-check-circle"></i></h3>
            <fieldset>
            <textarea class = "textarea-script" id="script" style="display: none;"></textarea>
            </fieldset>
        </form>
    </div>

<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
 $(".script-link").click(function() {
   $("#icon").hide();
   $("#icon2").show();
   $("#script").show(); 
 });
});
```

The idea behind it is: 1) An icon from Font-Awesome showing success, 2) A sentence saying your script has been approved to run, 3) you can click on the script (which is a hyperlink) and this is where I wrote some small javascript function to hide the icon (and show a smaller one in the corner), and show a text-box containing the script in question.

I used some animations to make all transitions (like the big icon to the small icon) look smooth. Howevever, difficulties arrise when the container switches size. What happens:

i) I click the 'script' hyperlink.
ii) Icon shrinks in the top right, textarea appears in the container, however it is way smaller than the icon, so the container size changes. However, the change is rather abrupt and doesn't fit well with the design.

I researched about transitions and tried the following:

```
#contact {
    background: #F9F9F9;
    padding: 25px;
    margin: 150px 0;
    box-shadow: 0 0 20px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 0 5px 5px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.24);
    transition:all 5s;  /* this */ 
  }
```

I also tried the same setting for the `.container`, but it doesn't work. The container size just changes immediatelly according to the size of the textbox and it doesn't look very pretty. I would very much appreciate your suggestions!

Answer (score 0):

Its better if you create a snippet of your codes, so we can see your result as well. But i think if you use this css code, you'll give the right result:

```
#contact *, #contact{
    transition: all 5s linear !important
 }
```